# Do compiled templates (in templates_c) contain URL data, or get corrupted?

Tags: civievent

I use price-sets with events, where users enter the number of seats/tickets wanted. Lately, and randomly, users get tickets added that they didn't order (e.g., they enter '1' at price_1 and after confirmation, they have '10' at price_2 in addition to '1' at price_1. Since it is random (and I haven't been able to reproduce it myself) I thought it was a browser/memory sort of problem. And, I understand that if BASEURL is not set correctly throught the session (Controller) can error out.
I don't know if this is due to session timeouts. I have cleared cache, checked configuration of paths, directories and all that. If a template were 'corrupted' could that cause it? And can I safely clear/refresh all the compiled templates under templates_c?
Civicrm 4.5 (will be updating soon ISA)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part, yes you can safely delete the contents of `/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/`.  That is a recommended step in the [upgrade process](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#UpgradingCiviCRMforDrupal7-10.ClearCache)